# New DbContext puts old data into database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I'm testing business logic (in sqlserver db) using auto-generated DbContext and MSTest framework. DbContext maps only part of entities and is used mainly in web api odata controllers. The testing pattern is:

```
protected U2Db Db; //auto-generated DbContext
protected DbContextTransaction CurrentTransaction;

[TestInitialize]
public void BeforeEveryTest(){
    Db = new U2Db();
    CurrentTransaction = 
       Db.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);   
}

[TestMethod]
public void Method1() {
    var o = new Order() {Tag="Method1"};
    Db.Orders.Add(o);
    Db.TrySave(); //custom extension. wraps SaveChanges and reports errors if exist

    //checks inner db tables, service broker queues etc. 
    ....
}
[TestMethod]
public void Method2() {

    var o = new Order() {Tag="Method2"};
    Db.Orders.Add(o);
    Db.TrySave(); //wraps SaveChanges and reports errors if exist

    ....
}
[TestCleanup]
public void AfterEveryTest() {
    if (Db == null) return;
    try
    {
        if (CurrentTransaction != null)
        {
            CurrentTransaction.Rollback();
            CurrentTransaction.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { };

    Db.Dispose();
}
```

If I run any test manually, it works as expected. If I start running a batch of tests (sequentially, single-threaded), some of them fail. What i see in Server Profiler is that transactions work as expected, but in failing tests database gets records which were used in previously run tests, which makes me feel like DbContext is not actually a 'new' instance. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Tests in general should be stateless to avoid these kind of errors. Don't use a field for your DBContext, but instantiate a separate variable in each test like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Method1() {
    var db = new U2Db();
    var o = new Order() {Tag="Method1"};
    db.Orders.Add(o);
    db.TrySave(); //custom extension. wraps SaveChanges and reports errors if exist

    //checks inner db tables, service broker queues etc. 
    ....
}
```